# Auto selection of free device in exclusive compute mode (when cudaSetDevice is not used) isn't working

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I recently got access to 4 GPUs (Tesla M2070) and I am trying to get previously working CUDA to use them well. My code runs on one GPU only and I would like to run several instances concurrently. I would like the code to automatically pick an open GPU whenever it is run.

I believe that this should be doable with no problem. The [Cuda Toolkit Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#device-selection) says, "If no call to cudaSetDevice() is made, the current device is device 0." However these two threads (thread [1](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/415723/choosing-cuda-device-programmatically/) and [2](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/521594/how-to-get-fastest-free-gpu-cutgetmaxgflopsdeviceid-always-same-device/)) and later in the [Cuda Toolkit Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#compute-modes) it is indicated that if the GPUs are set in a compute exclusive mode (exclusive thread or process) that the runtime API should choose a free GPU (instead of always 0) if cudaSetDevice is not called.

This is exactly the situation I am in. The GPUs are set to exclusive thread (see nvidia-smi output below) and I do not call cudaSetDevice (see code below) however when I run two instances of my code one process runs on device zero and the other fails. Both report to be set to device zero.

Does anyone have ideas on why a free device isn't automatically being selected or how to fix it.

Thank you,

Greg

Here is the output of the successful process:

```
GPU:

************** CUDA active **************


== mean and stdev of uniformly distributed (0,1] random numbers ==

Device calculation:

Device 0: "Tesla M2070"
mean  = 0.500187
stdev = 0.282953

*****************************************
```

Here is the output of the failed code:

```
GPU:
PottsCUDA: d_kernel_ran.cu:60: void d_ran(int, long int): Assertion `cudaRet==cudaSuccess' failed.

************** CUDA active **************


== mean and stdev of uniformly distributed (0,1] random numbers ==

Device calculation:

Device 0: "Tesla M2070"
/opt/gridengine/default/spool/compute-0-4/job_scripts/27865: line 47: 45678 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./PottsCUDA
```

Here is the output of nvidia-smi:

```
Mon Oct  5 15:48:54 2015       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 346.89     Driver Version: 346.89         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla M2070         Off  | 0000:49:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   N/A    P0    N/A /  N/A |      9MiB /  5375MiB |      0%    E. Thread |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla M2070         Off  | 0000:4A:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   N/A    P0    N/A /  N/A |      9MiB /  5375MiB |      0%    E. Thread |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla M2070         Off  | 0000:4B:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   N/A    P0    N/A /  N/A |      9MiB /  5375MiB |      0%    E. Thread |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla M2070         Off  | 0000:4C:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   N/A    P0    N/A /  N/A |      9MiB /  5375MiB |      0%    E. Thread |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is (an approximately) minimum working example of my code. I am using cuda 7.0 and compiling with arch=compute_20 and code=sm_20.

main.ccp:

```
#include "d_kernel_ran.h"
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int  main() 
{   

    // == CUDA check ==
    printf("\n");
    printf("************** CUDA active **************\n");
    printf("\n");

    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("== mean and stdev of uniformly distributed (0,1] random numbers ==\n");
        printf("\n");

        unsigned long seed_gpu = 170786;
        long ncycles = 10000000;

        // - device
        printf("Device calculation:\n");
        d_ran(seed_gpu, ncycles);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("*****************************************\n\n");
    fflush(stdout);


    return 0;
}
```

d_kernel_ran.cu:

```
#include "d_kernel_ran.h"
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

__global__ void ranInit( curandState* state, int seed, long N )
{
    int id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    if (id < N) {
        if (seed < 0) {
            seed = -seed;
        }
        curand_init ( seed, id, 0, &state[id] );
    }
} 

__global__ void ranGen( curandState* globalState, long N ) 
{
    int id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    if (id < N) {
        curandState localState = globalState[id];
        float RANDOM = curand_uniform( &localState );
        globalState[id] = localState; 
    }
}

__global__ void MCMC( curandState* globalState, float* d_ranArray, long N ) 
{
    int id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    if (id < N) {
        curandState localState = globalState[id];
        float RANDOM = curand_uniform( &localState );
        globalState[id] = localState;

        d_ranArray[id] = RANDOM;
    }
}

void d_ran(int seed, long ncycles) {

    long N = ncycles;

    // initialization of device arrays
    float* d_ranArray; 

    int memsize= N*sizeof(float);
    cudaError_t cudaRet;

    cudaRet = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_ranArray, memsize);
    int dev = 0;
    cudaGetDevice(&dev);
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);
    printf("\nDevice %d: \"%s\"\n", dev, deviceProp.name);
    assert(cudaRet==cudaSuccess);


    // initialization of host arrays
    float* h_ranArray;

    h_ranArray = (float*) malloc(memsize);
    assert(h_ranArray);

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) { 
        h_ranArray[i]=(float)0;
    }


    // copy host -> device
    cudaRet = cudaMemcpy(d_ranArray, h_ranArray, memsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
    assert(cudaRet==cudaSuccess); 


    // initialize blocks
    long threadsPerBlock=512;

    long blocksPerGrid = N/threadsPerBlock;
    if (N%threadsPerBlock) blocksPerGrid++;

    dim3 dim_grid, dim_block;

    dim_grid.x=blocksPerGrid;
    dim_grid.y=1;
    dim_grid.z=1;

    dim_block.x=threadsPerBlock;
    dim_block.y=1;
    dim_block.z=1;


    // setup rngs
    curandState* devStates;
    cudaMalloc( &devStates, N*sizeof( curandState ) );
    ranInit <<< dim_grid, dim_block >>> ( devStates, seed, N );


    // generate random numbers
    ranGen <<< dim_grid, dim_block >>> ( devStates, N );


    // perform sum
    MCMC <<< dim_grid, dim_block >>> ( devStates, d_ranArray, N );


    // copy device -> host
    cudaRet = cudaMemcpy(h_ranArray, d_ranArray, memsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    assert(cudaRet==cudaSuccess); 


    // free device memory
    cudaRet = cudaFree(devStates); 
    assert(cudaRet==cudaSuccess);
    cudaRet = cudaFree(d_ranArray); 
    assert(cudaRet==cudaSuccess); 


    // printing result
    float h_agg = (float)0;
    float h_agg2 = (float)0;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) { 
        h_agg += h_ranArray[i];
        h_agg2 += h_ranArray[i]*h_ranArray[i];
        #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("%f\n",h_ranArray[i]);
        #endif
    }

    float mean = h_agg / (float)N;
    float stdev = std::pow(( h_agg2 / (float)N - mean*mean ),(float)0.5);

    printf("mean  = %f\n",mean);
    printf("stdev = %f\n",stdev);

    // free host memory
    free(h_ranArray);

}
```

d_kernel_ran.h merely has the declaration of d_ran.

Comment: You are running CUDA 7.  It's a known issue.  Upgrade to CUDA 7.5

Comment: @Robert, Thank you for your quick response. Sorry for the duplicate question in my previous days' research into this I didn't find the question "Cuda Compute Mode and 'CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED".